# Custom Class CLed doesnt change color always

Tags: c++, image, class, mfc, dialog

I have a  user interface where I want to  change a Picture color according to the connection stability, simulating a ON/OFF LED.  But the problem is that it only works when going red. And in fact, in another "LED" it goes green without telling to.

The rectangle that goes red in the images

[image]
[image]

I have tried with things like m_statusMotor.UpdateWindow() or even UpdateData(0). However it does not work. When debugging I have seen that the value m_statusMotor.m_color changes correctly to 0, but doesnt change the LED color.

So this is what My class CLed does:

```
void CLed::OnPaint()
{
  CPaintDC dc(this);
  CRect r;
  GetClientRect(r);
  CBrush b1;
  switch(m_color){
  case 0:
    b1.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0)); // verde
    break;
  case 1:
    b1.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0)); // rojo
    break;
  case 2:
    b1.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 118, 0)); // ambar
    break;
  default:
    b1.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(160, 160, 160)); // gris
    break;
  }
  dc.SelectObject(&b1);
  dc.Rectangle(r);
}
```

This is where it does change to red:

```
if(!misoc1.Connect(m_ipMotor, m_portMotor)){
                            if(!connectedmotor) m_log.AddString("No conecta con el puerto de motor"); 
                            connectedmotor = true;
                            firststrmotor = false;
                            m_statusMotor.m_color = 1;
                            m_statusMotor.Invalidate(true);
                            m_log.UpdateWindow();
                            UpdateData(0);
                            m_statusMotor.UpdateWindow();

                    }else connectedmotor = false;
```

And this is where it doenst change to green

```
    if(!firststrmotor){
                        m_log.AddString("Motor OK");
                        m_log.UpdateWindow();
                        m_statusMotor.m_color = 0;
                        UpdateData(0);
                        m_statusMotor.UpdateWindow();

                    }
```

m_statusMotor is CLed class;

Any ideas why it works some times and some times not??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> function1()
> {
>     m_statusMotor.m_color = 1;
>     m_statusMotor.Invalidate(true);
>     m_statusMotor.UpdateWindow();
>     ...
> }
>
> function2()
> {
>     m_statusMotor.m_color = 0;
>     m_statusMotor.UpdateWindow();
>     ...
> }
> ```

In the first function you have correctly called `Invalidate`, followed by the optional `UpdateWindow` (`UpdateWindow` can be useful here if the function is blocking windows messages)

In the second function you forgot to call `Invalidate`, you just called `UpdateWindow` which does not have any effect in this case. There is nothing to invalidate, so no paint messages will be sent, as explained in documentation:

[`UpdateWindow:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatewindow)

> The `UpdateWindow` function updates the client area of the specified
>   window by sending a `WM_PAINT` message to the window if the window's
>   update region is not empty. The function sends a `WM_PAINT` message
>   directly to the window procedure of the specified window, bypassing
>   the application queue. If the update region is empty, no message is
>   sent.

Therefore, call `Invalidate()` followed by the optional `UpdateWindow()`.

Or call [`RedrawWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#redrawwindow) which will invalidate and update immediately, as noted in comments.

<sub>Side note, consider using `CDC::FillSolidRect` in your `OnPaint` function.</sub>

Comment: If you are always going to `Invalidate(true); UpdateWindow();` you can coalesce these calls into `RedrawWindow();` (which uses default flags of `RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW | RDW_ERASE`).